# How to get a np.ndarray shallow copy with indexing?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a np.ndarray,and using mask to get a subset:

```
a = np.arange(9)
b = a[[0,2,4]]
# or 
c = a[a%2==0]
```

What I want to do is ensure synchronous modification between the two. If I change the elements of `a`, I want `b` and `c` change simultaneously.

```
a[0] = 9
b[0]==c[0]==9 # True
```

In addition, I actually using structured array or recarray, how to make sure I shallow copy subset of those two type of array?

Comment: A shallow copy doesn't really make any sense in this context, shallow copies apply to structures that reference other structures, which isn't the case here.

Comment: Note, using integer-sequence based indexing will *always* create a copy, not a view

Comment: With `numpy` there are `views` and `copies`.  Unless we have object dtype, there isn't a distinction between deep copy and (shallow) copy.  With structured arrays the same view/copy distiction applies - with the added note that field indexing produces a view.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.rec.html#indexing-and-assignment-to-structured-arrays documents `structured arrays`.  Note the use of `view` on this page - it's being used in a precise, technical sense.  Similarly, the main `indexing` page is https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html, with equally precise use of `view/copy`.

Comment: You will get a view if you index with *slices* (or a mix of slices and scalar integer indices when you have higher dimensional arrays),  e.g. `a[:5:2]`.  If you index with a *list* of integers (e.g. `a[[0, 2, 4]]`) or a boolean mask (e.g. `a[a%2==0]`), you will always get a copy.